How to push a docker image to ecr using aws cdk go
I am using aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2 - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2. I am using the existing constructs to create an ecr repository aswell as building a docker image.
How can i push the built docker image to the newly created ecr repo.
    repo := awsecr.NewRepository(stack, jsii.String(name+"-ecr"), &awsecr.RepositoryProps{
        RepositoryName: jsii.String(providerName + "/" + serviceName),
    })

    dockerImage := awsecrassets.NewDockerImageAsset(stack, jsii.String(name+"-ecr-image"), &awsecrassets.DockerImageAssetProps{
        Directory: jsii.String("."),
        File:      jsii.String("some-path/Dockerfile"),
    })
    ```


You would use the cdk-ecr-deployment construct
Modified example from the docs:
ecrdeploy.NewECRDeployment(this, jsii.String("DeployDockerImage1"), &ECRDeploymentProps{
    Src: ecrdeploy.NewDockerImageName(image.ImageUri),
    Dest: ecrdeploy.NewDockerImageName(repo.RepositoryUriForTag('myTag')),
})


I did just come across this but Im having trouble installing this package. Could you also update answer on how to install it?

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment-go/' not found

go get github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment-go/cdkecrdeployment/v3
go: module github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment-go/cdkecrdeployment/v3: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/kay/go/1.22.4/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3832d01b81d0fc3e8238b631c9e88566faf4d09b153210520f4074f0d584600c: exit status 128:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment-go/' not found

Try the install command listed at the link in the answer: go get github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment-go. If that doesn't work (could be a bug) - try removing the -go from the name.
